# Form A import B and import A causes troubles

Tags: python

I have a following problem. I have this folder structure:

```
folder
├──script.py
├──utils.py
└──venv
```

I would like to import functions from utils.py into script.py. When I try this `from utils import function_a, function_b` everything works. But when I try `import utils` I got an error `NameError: name 'function_a' is not defined`.

Whats the difference between `from utils import function_a, function_b` and `import utils` in this case? And how can I fix it, please?

Comment: You need to specify module name , In your case utils.function_a() while calling.

Comment: have you tried `import utils.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**import module** : Nice when you are using many bits from the module. Drawback is that you'll need to qualify each reference with the module name.

**from module import ...** : Nice that imported items are usable directly without module name prefix. The drawback is that you must list each thing you use, and that it's not clear in code where something came from.

Answer (score 2):

If you are importing the module itself, then you have to specify what you want to use from the module with the `.` operator:

```py
import utils

utils.function_a()
utils.function_b()
```

Comment: And this is the preferred way to do it, because it avoids accidental name clashes.